# give css to parent if child has certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do I apply css to parent if his child have a certain class?

for example:

```
<p>
     <span class="validationMessage">Last Name is required field</span>
</p>
```

I want to give the p tag css base on that the his child element has class called "validationMessage"

Comment: `$('p').has('.validationMessage')`? http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/#post-255

Answer (score 1):

Try [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector:

```
 $("p:has(span.validationMessage)").css(yourPCss);
```

Have a look:
http://jsfiddle.net/jdfcr/

Comment: how can I do it without approaching p tag? because it's sometimes a p and sometimes a div

Comment: @eyalhalperin you can do it like this: `$(":has(>span.validationMessage)").css("border","1px dotted #090");`

Answer (score 0):

[.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
$('span.validationMessage').parent().css(style);
```

also look at

[.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)